# How to draw array with arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows

I want to draw this:

[image]

Till now I am able to draw this much but struggling with red arrows

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
 3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3  \\
\hline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you accept a pure `TikZ` solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm},
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth]{
    3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3\\};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(\i)},
                evaluate=\i as \ntext using {int(\i-1)}] in {1,3,4,6} 
    \draw [{Stealth}-, red!70] (A-1-\ni.south west)--++(-90:5mm) node[below] {\ntext};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In beamer class it is giving error how to fix it for beamer class

Comment: it works with beamer as expected: just replace first code line with `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}`

Comment: @new_born Works with `beamer`. Add `[fragile]` option to frame containing this matrix or add `ampersand replacement=\&` into `matrix` options and replace all `&` with `\&`. Next time, inform us that you want to use `beamer`: it's an important information.

Comment: how can I change its fonts sizes?

Comment: @alper add `font` option in node's options

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and TikZ to draw the arrows by using the PGF/TikZ nodes created by `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{c}}[hvlines]
  3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [{Stealth}-,red]
    \draw (2-|1) -- ++(0,-4mm) node [below] {0} ; 
    \draw (2-|3) -- ++(0,-4mm) node [below] {2} ; 
    \draw (2-|4) -- ++(0,-4mm) node [below] {3} ; 
    \draw (2-|6) -- ++(0,-4mm) node [below] {5} ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

One more plain TikZ solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\draw (0,0) grid (8,1); 
\path (.5,.5) node{$3$} ++(1,0) node{$4$} 
++(1,0) node{$2$} ++(1,0) node{$1$} ++(1,0) node{$4$} 
++(1,0) node{$1$} ++(1,0) node{$2$} ++(1,0) node{$3$};
\foreach \i in {0,2,3,5}
\draw[latex-,red] (\i,0)--+(-90:1) node[below,black]{$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: you can use `foreach` in a `path` to shorten the code

```
\path (.5,.5) node{$3$} foreach \i in {4,2,1,4,1,2,3} {++(1,0) node{$\i$}};
```